# Mac OS X Uninitialized pointer behavior

Tags: c, macos, pointers

I bought an older book "A Guide To Kernel Exploitation" and have been trying to follow the first example in chapter 2 on my MacBook Air (M1). In the book the code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>

void big_stack_usage(){
   char big[200];
   memset(big, 'A', 200);
}

void ptr_un_initialized(){
   char *p;
   printf("Pointer value: %p\n", p);
}

int main(){
   big_stack_usage();
   ptr_un_initialized();
}
```

However the book shows the address of the pointer to be 0x41414141.
On my MacBook Air I see a random pointer every time I run the program.
If I change the first function to:

```
void big_stack_usage(){
   char big[10000];
   memset(big, 'A', 10000);
}
```

Then the pointer is always 0. So why is it random for a small array size and 0 for a large array size.

Whats going on here? Any why is it different than the book?

Comment: Given the focus on exploitation, I assume you're interested in what the code actually does under the hood, and you already know that it's undefined behavior in C and in principle can do nearly anything?  For most such questions, the way to answer them is to read the assembly generated by the compiler, look at where it reads and writes from, and keep track of what's in the relevant registers and memory locations.

Comment: If you want help in this process, you should specify the exact compiler version and options you are using, or better, include the assembly in your question.

Comment: Just to your last question, undefined behavior like this can vary greatly between even very similar compiler, OS, and library combinations.  And you are using a completely different combination from what the book is using.  It would have been far more surprising if they were the same.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering if there was some new kernel security feature I did not know about. But You pointed me in a good direction! I will check the assembly to get a better idea. That had not crossed my mind.

Comment: Everything in your question is happening in user space; the kernel and its security features aren't really involved at all.  I think this example is more meant to illustrate the general principle that the value read from uninitialized variables *can*, potentially, be related to data used elsewhere in the program.  You shouldn't interpret it as any kind of guarantee that this *will* happen in any particular instance.

Comment: ok, that makes much more sense.